# 'messages is not a function' nodeJs

Tags: node.js, express, connect-flash

## **messages is not a function**

- Why `!= messages('message',locals)` is  showing me error
- even though it is right

### Please help me to find error. thank you

app.js

```
app.use(require('connect-flash')());
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
```

users.js

```
router.post('/POST', function(req, res){
    user = new user();
    user.firstName = req.body.first;
    user.LastName = req.body.last;
    user.email = req.body.email;
    user.password = req.body.password;
user.save(function (err) {
    if(err){
        console.log(err);
    }else{
        req.flash('success', 'You have been registered');
        res.redirect('/');
    }
});
});
```

message.pug

```
.messages
    each type in Object.keys(messages)
        each message in messages[type]
            div(class="alert alert-"+type) #{message}
```

layout.pug

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css')
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
  body
    nav.navbar.navbar-expand-md.navbar-dark.bg-dark.mb-4
      button.navbar-toggler(type='button', data-toggle='collapse', data-target='#navbarCollapse', aria-controls='navbarCollapse', aria-expanded='false', aria-label='Toggle navigation')
        span.navbar-toggler-icon
      #navbarCollapse.collapse.navbar-collapse
        ul.navbar-nav.mr-auto
          li.nav-item
            a.nav-link(href='/') Home
              span.sr-only (current)
          li.nav-item
            a.nav-link(href='/users') Register
          li.nav-item
            a.nav-link(href='#') Disabled
        form.form-inline.mt-2.mt-md-0(method='post' action='')
          input.form-control.mr-sm-2(type='text', placeholder='Search', aria-label='Search')
          button.btn.btn-outline-success.my-2.my-sm-0(type='submit') Search
    != messages('message',locals)
    block content
    br
    hr
    footer
      p Copyright &copy; 2019
        script(src='/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js')
        script(src='/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js')
```

error

```
TypeError: C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\views\layout.pug:23
    21|           input.form-control.mr-sm-2(type='text', placeholder='Search', aria-label='Search')
    22|           button.btn.btn-outline-success.my-2.my-sm-0(type='submit') Search
  > 23|     != messages('message',locals)
    24|     block content
    25|     br
    26|     hr

messages is not a function
    at eval (eval at wrap (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:60:46)
    at template (eval at wrap (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\pug-runtime\wrap.js:6:10), <anonymous>:87:239)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:418:38)
    at Object.exports.renderFile (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:408:21)
    at View.exports.__express [as engine] (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\pug\lib\index.js:455:11)
    at View.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1008:7)
    at C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\app.js:94:7
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:71:5)
    at trim_prefix (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:315:13)
    at C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at Layer.handle_error (C:\Users\User\WebstormProjects\crudApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:67:12)
```

Comment: Try `!{messages('message',locals)}`

Comment: sorry its not working `> 23|     !{messages('message',locals)}
------------^`    
and error is `unexpected text "!{mes" `

Comment: post your `package.json`

Comment: package.json

`{
  "name": "crudapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
    "debug": "~2.6.9",
    "express": "~4.16.0",
    "express-messages": "^1.0.1",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^5.3.1",
    "http-errors": "~1.6.2",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.7",
    "morgan": "~1.9.0",
    "pug": "2.0.0-beta11"
  }
}`

Comment: Router included below `app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});` in app.js ?

Comment: yes i have included that in app.js

Comment: I have replicated your code, The code which you have posted here is working fine. Something is wrong with the code that not posted here.

Answer (score 4):

I don' know if you already did, but make sure that the following declaration is before app.use(app,router) or any route use:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
  res.locals.messages = require('express-messages')(req, res);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that the module installed is express-messages not express message

In the app.js have the following code:

`app.use(function (req, res, next) { res.locals.messages = require('express-messages') (req , res); next(); });`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the [answer from Yaco](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55234269/10026310)

Also make sure you have [express-session](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session) installed.

Placing the configuration of express-messages before declaring my routes,
I get the error: `req.flash() requires sessions`

A configuration like this might fix the error for you:

```js
const session = require('express-session');
```

```js
app.use(session({
  secret: 'secret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
```